# how to connect postgresql server remotely

Tags: centos, postgresql-9.1

I have created an instance of postgres in VM.(cent-os 7)

I fail to connect to that server remotely using tableplus app.

can someone help me sort this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the hostname and user name on the command line psql as a good test.  This will help you identify the issues, then you will have the values to use in the GUI tool.

psql -h $dbhost -U $dbuser $dbname